# How to split characters on x-axis and assign color for them

Tags: r, ggplot2, split

I'm new in R and ggplot2. Currently I have a plot like this:

[image: http://imgur.com/lJFXVfZ.png]

And I want something like that:

[image: http://imgur.com/czXg0Yb.png]

Unfortunately I have no idea, how to split characters on x-axis and assign them a different color.

This is my code:

```
attach(trustData)

ag <- aggregate(trustData, by = list(type = face_category_and_gender2_ZAUFANIE), mean)

plot <- ggplot(data = ag, aes(x = type, y = response)) + list(geom_point(colour = 'red'))

plot
```

As new member, I can't put here more than 2 links, so example of already aggregated data is in comments

Thanks!

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example data.  You have to create a group column to get that.  If you show some example data, it will be easier for us to help

Comment: http://imgur.com/qdDqhGQ.png

Here you go

Comment: Ok, I'm going to update. 
K - Woman
M - Men

Comment: The image you showed, is it the `ag` data or the original 'trustData`?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Thank you very much! Is there any possibility to make red and blue point in one line? Like in 2nd picture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can `separate` the 'type' column and then do the plotting

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
ag %>% 
    separate(type, into = c("val", "Type"), "(?=[A-Z])", remove = FALSE) %>%
    mutate(val = factor(val, levels = sort(unique(as.numeric(val)))),
            Type = factor(Type, levels =c("M", "K"), labels = c("Men", "Woman"))) %>%
    ggplot(., aes(x = val, y = response, col = Type)) + 
                geom_point()
```

---

Or instead of `factor` use the `case_when` from `dplyr`

```
ag %>%
   separate(type, into = c("val", "Type"), "(?=[A-Z])", remove = FALSE) %>% 
   mutate(val = factor(val, levels = sort(unique(as.numeric(val)))),
          Type = case_when(.$Type == "M" ~ "Men", TRUE ~ "Woman")) %>%
   ggplot(., aes(x = val, y = response, col = Type)) + 
                geom_point()
```

[image]

#### data

```
ag <- structure(list(type = c("12K", "12M", "15K", "15M", "1K", "1M", 
"4K", "4M", "7K", "7M", "9K", "9M"), response = c(41.83, 42.45, 
40.61, 40.69, 64.59, 57.88, 61.2, 54.71, 49.23, 48.24, 44.27, 
45.09)), .Names = c("type", "response"), row.names = c(NA, -12L
), class = "data.frame")
```